# How to prepare iron(II) carbonate from iron(III) chloride?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, synthesis

Now, this is an awkward reaction first of all. I know how to prepare $\ce{Fe2(CO3)3}$ from $\ce{FeCl3}$:

$$\ce{2FeCl3 + 3Na2CO3 -> 6NaCl + Fe2(CO3)3}$$

But the question is asking for $\ce{FeCO3}$. It seems to be an impossible task but since this was asked in a public examination, does anybody know how to prepare $\ce{FeCO3}$ from $\ce{FeCl3}$ (in one, two or three reactions)?

Comment: I can't see how reducing it would be a problem

Comment: Also, $\ce{Fe2(CO3)3}$ does not really exist.

Comment: @Mithoron could you please explain how I could reduce it?

Comment: @IvanNeretin It doesn't really exist? How? Why?

Comment: Being a salt of a weak acid and a weak base, it hydrolizes instantly and completely upon mixing. But that shouldn't bother us, for we don't need it anyway. We need $\ce{FeCO3}$; it is more or less OK.

Answer (score 4):

$$\ce{2FeCl3 + 2H2O + SO2 -> 2FeCl2 + H2SO4 + 2HCl}$$

$$\ce{FeCl2 + Na2CO3 -> FeCO3 + 2NaCl}$$

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. For more information in general have a look at the [help]. At the moment this reads more like a comment than an actual answer - could you elaborate a little more. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) on any question/answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest method I can think of:

$\mathrm{2FeCl_3+Fe\rightarrow3FeCl_2}$

$\mathrm{FeCl_2+Na_2CO_3\rightarrow FeCO_3+2NaCl}$

It only uses iron metal and sodium carbonate, which are readily available. Sodium bicarbonate (baking soda) can be used instead of sodium carbonate, but a greater mass would be required. The iron metal should have a high surface area, perhaps in the form of iron powder or steel wool.