# Precipitation of CaCl2 and FeCl3 in Na2CO3

Tags: solubility, precipitation

Why does $\ce{CaCl2}$ gives precipitation of $\ce{CaCO3}$ when $\ce{Na2CO3}$ is added, but $\ce{FeCl3}$ does not give the precipitation of $\ce{Fe2(CO3)3}$ in $\ce{Na_2CO_3}$  ?

Comment: If it gives a precipitate then it isn't/is slightly soluble.

Comment: @KianStevens ... I wanted to know the reason ... If I'm correct or not ...

Comment: What about the down vote ?? Is it not related .?

Comment: Obviously, $\ce{FeCl3}$ does not give the precipitate of  $\ce{CaCO3}$, because, er... why would it? There is no  $\ce{Ca}$ in it, to begin with.

Comment: @Ivan ...  ... By precipitate , I meant $Fe_2CO_3$ ...

Comment: Man ... What's the reason for down vote ? Is it not related .?

Comment: Well, then here's another correct (if probably useless) answer for you: $\ce{FeCl3}$ contains  $\ce{Fe^3+}$, and $\ce{FeCO3}$ contains  $\ce{Fe^2+}$, and the former would not just up and transform into the latter (unless this is a redox, which it isn't).

Comment: @Ivan ... I've edited my question .. I hope you would go through it ...

Comment: Now we've come to the heart of the matter. See, $\ce{Fe2(CO3)3}$ (yes, you've got the formula right this time around) is unstable due to hydrolysis. For all practical purposes, it doesn't _exist_.

Comment: Yes, iron carbonate does not exist. See this post: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64331/is-iron-iii-carbonate-stable-in-water

Comment: @Ivan ... Is it something like $Fe_2(CO)_3$ is unstable due to decomposition for polarization ...?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by _"decomposition for polarization"_. Other than that, yes, it is unstable.

Comment: @NilayGhosh You've just sent the OP to an _unanswered_ post with pretty much the same question. I don't think this is going to help.

Comment: @Ivan Guess that would be a duplicate...

Comment: @NilayGhosh You need to have either an accepted or upvoted answer in the previously asked question to close this as a duplicate,

Comment: @Pritt I am aware of that fact. I was just joking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This must have been a very good question for a geochemist. They'd give you a complete answer with details of why $\ce{Fe2(CO3)3}$ does not but $\ce{Fe2O3}$ exist in our surrounding. Yet, I would like to give only a simple answer for the question: No, $\ce{Fe2(CO3)3}$ does not form (in sort) when you added $\ce{Na2(CO3)3}$ to an aqueous solution of $\ce{FeCl3}$. The reason?

An aqueous solution of $\ce{FeCl3}$ is acidic because $\ce{FeCl3}$ is a salt of a strong acid $(\ce{HCl})$ and a weak base $(\ce{Fe(OH)3})$. Thus an aqueous solution of $\ce{FeCl3}$ is in following equilibrium:
$$\ce {Fe^{3+} + 2H2O <=> [FeOH]^{2+} + H3O+ }$$
Thus, $\ce{H3O+}$ ions in solution can react with added $\ce{CO3^{2-}}$ ions to form carbonic acid $(\ce{H2(CO3)3})$,which can decomposed to form $\ce{CO2}$  and $\ce{H2O}$. Remaining $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ will combine with left behind $\ce{OH-}$ ions to make $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$, which would decomposed to $\ce{Fe2O3}$. Thus, when $\ce{Na2CO3}$ is added to an aqueous solution of $\ce{FeCl3}$, one can expect the following sequence of reactions to be taken place: 
$$\ce {FeCl3 (aq) + Na2CO3 (aq) -> [Fe2(CO3)]^{3+} (aq) -> Fe2O3 (s) + CO2 (g) + H2O (l)}$$